# Проектирование реляционной БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Я разрабатываю базу данных. У меня встал вопрос по следующей части проектирования. В бд есть следующие 3 таблицы:
[image: Таблицы]

Логика такая: в одно подразделение может входить много клиентов. В тоже время это подразделение может выполнять несколько рассылок своим клиентам. Один клиент может получить несколько рассылок от своего подразделения.
Как видно из скрина получается некая циклическая связь между таблицами. Вопрос: такое вообще возможно, просто я слышал, что такая связь - это ошибка. Правильно ли я поступаю? Если нет, то как сделать лучше?

Answer (score 1):

В вашей схеме нет зацикленности. Ограничения внешних ключей определяют порядок внесения данных и как видно из схемы это вполне возможно. Если вы посмотрите на реальное зацикливание внешних ключей то убедитесь что попытка внесения данных в любую из участвующих в петле связей таблиц попросту не возможна.
Давайте посмотрим не примере трех таблиц ссылающихся друг на друга (для близости к вашему варианту):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    id_b int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    id_c int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    id_a int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT c_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Определим ограничения внешних ключей:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS a
    ADD CONSTRAINT lnk_a_b FOREIGN KEY (id_b)
    REFERENCES b (id) MATCH FULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS b
    ADD CONSTRAINT lnk_b_c FOREIGN KEY (id_c)
    REFERENCES c (id) MATCH FULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS c
    ADD CONSTRAINT lnk_c_a FOREIGN KEY (id_a)
    REFERENCES a (id) MATCH FULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Попробуем добавить данные в каждую таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO a(id_b) VALUES(1);
```

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "a" violates foreign key constraint
> "lnk_a_b" DETAIL:  Key (id_b)=(1) is not present in table "b".

```
INSERT INTO b(id_c) VALUES(1);
```

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint
> "lnk_b_c" DETAIL:  Key (id_c)=(1) is not present in table "c".

```
INSERT INTO c(id_a) VALUES(1);
```

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "c" violates foreign key constraint
> "lnk_c_a" DETAIL:  Key (id_a)=(1) is not present in table "a".

Можете попробовать сами [здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/KY-Avb3Z)

В вашей схеме код клиента включен в качестве поля в таблицу рассылок. Это значит, что в одной уникальной рассылке может быть только один клиент. Если подумать то рассылка должна включать множество клиентов и один клиент может входить в несколько рассылок. Это отношение "многие ко многим" реализуется через промежуточную таблицу с составным ключом ид_рассылки + ид_клиента и связи должны быть назначены не напрямую а через эту промежуточную таблицу, ид_клиента убрать из таблицы рассылок. Тогда у вас получится то что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и пояснение. Значит в моём случае всё нормально и такое вполне может быть, или можно сделать лучше и стоит ещё подумать над проектировкой этой части?

Comment: Лучше сделать можно почти всегда, собственно поэтому и говорят, что лучшее это враг хорошего. Если данная схема соответствует потребностям вашей предметной области, то вы можете ее использовать. Однако помните, что ограничение внешнего ключа само по себе не является элементом оптимизирующим выборку. Тесть при создании ограничений внешнего ключа имеет смысл создать индексы в подчиненных таблицах по полям включенным в ключ, для оптимизации выборки.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про организацию отношений "многие ко многим" так как у вас в одну уникальную рассылку можно включить только одного клиента.